# Device volume won't mute

Tags: ios, xcode, voip, avaudiosession

I have a VOIP app, I use AVAudioSession and set the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category and `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker` option and it works great.

The only problem I just can not solve is that during a conversation the user can not reduce the volume totally and the device volume is stuck on one "cube" (When using the device controls). That prevents the user from muting the voice.

Any idea why this is happening ?

BTW - I can reproduce this in iOS 5 - 8. 
Thanks